# Read table data from Excel file with python

Tags: python, excel

I currently have an Excel workbook with some graphs (charts?). The graphs are plotted from numerical values. I can access the values in LibreOffice if I right click on the graph and select "Data table". These values are nowhere else in the file.

I would like to access these values programmatically with Python. I tried things like xlrd, but it seems xlrd ignores graphical elements. When I run it on my workbook I only get empty cells back.

Have you ever encountered this issue?

Sadly I cannot provide the file as it is confidential.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with graphical excel file. But i used to read normal excel with following code. have you tried this?

```
import xlrd

file = 'temp.xls'
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
for sheet in book.sheets():
  #to check columns in sheet
  if sheet.ncols:
    #row values
    row_list = sheet.row_values

for value in row_list:
  print(value)
```

Comment: Yes I tried. As mentioned above, this ignores graphical elements (like charts).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('path/name_of_your_file.xlsx')
print(df.head())
```

You should have a dataframe (df) to play with in python!

Comment: Really doesn't answer the question. I can read an excel file, I'm trying to access values stored in a chart (data table).